# Oracle database EXP default directory

Tags: oracle

I am trying to export a table under a user schema in oracle using the EXP command. I am doing this on the command line. This is the syntax that I used:

EXP scott/passcode TABLES=users STATISTICS=none INDEXES=n;

My export was successful with the result as follow:

[image]

However, I could not find where my table was exported to. I looked all over the internet, and I still don't know the default path of oracle EXP command. Please do not tell me anything about EXPDP. EXPDP and EXP are very different.

Comment: Any reason you didn't specify the `FILE=` parameter? It would make finding the file so much easier...

Comment: Classic export runs from client side so no default directory.Create a directory on your computer and run the exp command and export file is created in the same directory when you run `exp` and  if no file is specified the default file name  is `EXPDAT.DMP`

Comment: If you run second time without file parameter for different object(s) it will overwrite `EXPDAT.DMP` for that reason it's important to use parameter `file=xxx.dmp` to avoid overwriting

Comment: Are you running this in Windows?  In any case, what directory were you in when you invoked the `exp` command?  That is where the output files will be, and as @Kumar mentioned, without the `FILE=` parameter, you will end up with the default name.